# Ionic 2 Keyboard becomes slow when typing

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have been having issues with typing into textarea on android, The keyboard becomes slow when typing. I don't seem to know why that happening as I am not running any code on each keyPress/Input.

Below is my html code for the textarea

```html
<ion-footer>
  <ion-grid class="input-wrap">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-10>
        <ion-list no-lines>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-textarea #chatInput placeholder="Type a message" (keyup.enter)="sendMessage(chatInput)" [(ngModel)]="messageField"></ion-textarea>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-2>
        <button [disabled]="messageField == ''" ion-button clear icon-only item-right (click)="sendMessage(chatInput)">
          <ion-icon  name="ios-send" ios="ios-send" md="md-send"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-footer>
```

Any idea about solving this will be appreciated.

Comment: doubt  goes to sendMessage function, you many  have a blocking task there.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. I tried using textarea instead and it solved my problem:

```
<ion-footer>
  <ion-grid class="input-wrap">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-10>
        <ion-list no-lines>
          <ion-item>
            <textarea #chatInput placeholder="Type a message" (keyup.enter)="sendMessage(chatInput)" [(ngModel)]="messageField"></textarea>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-2>
        <button [disabled]="messageField == ''" ion-button clear icon-only item-right (click)="sendMessage(chatInput)">
          <ion-icon  name="ios-send" ios="ios-send" md="md-send"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-footer>
```